# How to create a terrain mesh from a heightmap in LibGdx

Tags: libgdx, terrain, heightmap

I am working on a top down game - currently the terrain is a tilemap that is generated based on a heightmap array that holds height values ranging from 0 to 255. I want to change this and instead render a terrain mesh. I understand the basic idea behind how meshes work but I cannot figure out how to actually translate a height matrix into a mesh. Any help on how to create and render the terrain mesh would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests/src/com/badlogic/gdx/tests/g3d/HeightMapTest.java